# What is the correct contextual use of input function? Does it have any functionality with defining a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, input

I recently finished code academy's python 3 course and started on runestone academy's thinkcspy as part of a python3 syllabus I found. I was wondering what practical use the input function has in conjunction with defining a function?

I'm at the beginning of this new course and they started by teaching input() before def function().
I was asked to simply write a program that prints the day someone returns from a holiday after user input for a start day and a length of time off. Also the days of the week are assigned values starting with Sunday as 0 till Sat as 6. Instead of simply assigning variables to inputs and printing a str result, I wanted to combine input functionality with a function I made and a dictionary.

This is what I wrote and it seems to get the job done:

'''

```
Week = { 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday', 0: 'Sunday'}

def date_of_return(start_date = int(input('Start date?')), length_of_stay = int(input('length of stay?'))):
return_key = (start_date + length_of_stay) % 7
return return_key, Week[return_key]
print(date_of_return())
```

'''
I'm just curious why code academy never taught any practical uses of input() function and only mentioned it once? It seems pretty useful to combine in a function so that a user can be prompted to input the correct arguments into the function instead of having to know the required parameters before hand? Or am I simply overthinking all this since its all beginner level..

Comment: You're using input to set *default parameter values*, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: So I tried it out in Spyder to see why it doesnt really make sense even though it works. Is it simply cause writing out the parameters as outside variables and keeping everything else the same works just the same and is more code efficient? And since both ways get the same result, there is no point in using input in a function definition? I was just trying to write out code that would prompt user input which apparently is done just with input() alone.